# Strange hosting questions in regards to godaddy and index,php

Tags: url, hosting, godaddy

I had a site (EE 1.6) that was on godaddy.  Something was changed in order to allow the pages to load with a ? in the url's.  ie: http://domain.com/index.php?/site/fine_art/

I am trying to move the site to a new server, I have upgraded to 1.7.3 for now.  But I can't figure out how to change the system to not use index.php? in the string.

I must have changed somethign somewhere but can't find it.  SO {path="site/fine_art"} will result in http://domain.com/index.php?/site/fine_art/ as the link.

Answer (score 1):

Force URL query strings
This is a safety mechanism for servers that do not support the PATH_INFO variable. NO